# knockoutjs call keeps executing, how can I call it only once?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I have this piece of code:

```
t._teacherOptions = ko.observable();

function getTeacherList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/Service.asmx/GetTeachers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(i) {
      if (i.d) {
        console.log(i.d);
        return t._teacherOptions(i.d);

      }
    },
    error: function(n) {
      u(n);
    }
  });
}

t.TeacherOptions = ko.computed(function() {
  getTeacherList();
  return t._teacherOptions();
});
```

And then my html:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.TeacherOptions(), value: Id, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

For some reason, when the page is opened, the function for getting the teacher list is continuously looping without stop.

I'm able to get the results I need but the loop keeps going and I need to stop that. Anything wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Why do you want `t.TeacherOptions` to be computed value? Also if `_teacherOption` is a list, why not use *observableArray*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping endlessly because your `TeacherOptions` (which is a `computed`) accesses `_teacherOptions` (hence creating a dependency) and since you're mutating the value of `_teacherOptions` in the `success` callback of your Ajax call, the `TeacherOptions` is being evaluated again  (because it depends on `_teacherOptions`) and issues the Ajax request again.

Try to call `getTeacherList()` outside of your `computed`:

```
t._teacherOptions = ko.observable();

function getTeacherList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/Service.asmx/GetTeachers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(i) {
      if (i.d) {
        console.log(i.d);
        return t._teacherOptions(i.d);

      }
    },
    error: function(n) {
      u(n);
    }
  });
}

getTeacherList();

t.TeacherOptions = ko.computed(function() {
  return t._teacherOptions();
});
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html)